# Fetch value from Map (Id,Id)

Tags: apex, trigger, map

I'm trying to fetch the Id of a custom object record so that I can update the record later in my code.

```
map<Id,Id> jToUp = new map<Id,Id>();
for(TargetxOpp__c txo: [SELECT Id, Opportunity__c FROM TargetxOpp__c
                         WHERE Opportunity__c IN :updatedOpps])
    jToUp.put(txo.Id, txo.Opportunity__c);
    system.debug('jToUp contains ' + jToUp);

List<TargetxOpp__c> updLinks = new List<TargetxOpp__c>();
for(Opportunity opp1 : updatedOpps){

    system.debug('opp1 contains' + opp1);

    Id jId = jToUp.get(opp1.Id);
    system.debug('jId contains ' + jId);

    Id target1 = newTargets.get(opp1.Identifier__c);

    TargetxOpp__c j1 = new TargetxOpp__c();
    j1.Id = jId;
    j1.Target__c = target1;

    updLinks.add(j1); 
}
update updLinks;
```

When I trigger the code, my debug log tells me that jToUp contains both the Id of the TargetxOpp__c record and it's related Opportunity record.

It also tells me that opp1 contains the same Opportunity Id.

But jId 'contains null' and I can't work out why?

**EDIT** just to clarify, obviously

```
Id jId = jToUp.get(opp1.Id);
```

Should fetch the TargetxOpp__c record Id from the map but it's not working because it's not assigning that Id to the variable jId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be adding a `TargetxOpp__c` ID is the map key and `TargetxOpp__c.Opportunity__c` which is presumably an `Opportunity` ID as the map value.

Then you are going a `get` (a lookup of the key value) on an `Opportunity` ID. But the keys are  `TargetxOpp__c` IDs hence null is always returned.

Perhaps reversing the map insert will fix:

```
jToUp.put(txo.Opportunity__c, txo.Id);
```

but the name `jToUp` doesn't make it very obvious what the intent is.

(You mention `AccountxOpp__c` in your edit but that isn't mentioned in the code.)

Comment: Thanks so just to be clear, the first *value* in a map is the key? I've removed the reference to AccountxOpp__c by the way, that was a typo,

Comment: @Alex Yes its key then value - see [Map.put](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_put).